# Bootstrap carousel not responsive to height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, height, carousel

I want to make a bootstrap carousel responsive to height so that it will rescale the image while maintaining the aspect ratio when changing the width and the height of the window the carousel is in.

The carousel is responsive to width by default, but I've run into a problem where I am not able to make it responsive to height changes.

I have tried some of the suggestions on similar questions to this, they have however not helped me solve this problem.

A JSFiddle on how I would like the images in the carousel to behave:

[like this](http://jsfiddle.net/bryandh/eu42sh52/)

HTML:

```
<div>
<img src="http://zoarchurch.co.uk/content/pages/uploaded_images/91.png" class="responsive-img" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.responsive-img {
    position: absolute;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

As you resize the result box you'll see that the image resizes depending on both the height and the width of the container it is in.

---

A JSFiddle with the [carousel](http://jsfiddle.net/bryandh/cuytnzja/2/)

HTML:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="http://zoarchurch.co.uk/content/pages/uploaded_images/91.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="item ">
            <img src="http://www.mildred.co/issueassets/22/14RSowlhat.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Carousel nav --> <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
 <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>

</div>
```

As you resize the result box you'll see that the image only resizes depending on the width of the container.

Comment: I dont see any difference between the two fiddle examples. 
However, you can try setting your images to a standard size. eg, 1280 * 300 Pixels and see how that responds. As it stands now, your images are about only 200-300 Pixels wide.

Comment: I'm confident the image sizes don't matter. The key to understanding the fiddles is to alter the width and height of the result containers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use background images for a div with width and height set to render in a carousel. Here you can have a look at the way it can be implemented.
http://jsfiddle.net/cuytnzja/4/

```css
.carousel-img{
    width: 100%;
    height:500px;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            
            <div class="carousel-img" style="background: url('http://zoarchurch.co.uk/content/pages/uploaded_images/91.png') no-repeat 50% 50% fixed">
                
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item ">
            <div class="carousel-img" style="background: url('http://www.mildred.co/issueassets/22/14RSowlhat.jpg') no-repeat 50% 50% fixed">
                            
            </div>            
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Carousel nav --> <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
 <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>

</div>
```

Comment: That is not exactly what I'm trying to do here, the thing is, I want the images in the carousel to resize depending on the width and height of the carousel. What your JSFiddle does is it keeps the image at a static size in both width and height.